# how do you get the specific style altered with a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Quick one, not sure if its possible.

How can I get the specific style altered with a CSS class using jQuery/JS.
Example:

html looks like:

```
<tab>

    <a class="anchor">a</a>

</tab>
```

CSS looks like:

```
a{border:1px}

.anchor{color:green}
```

So if i do something like :

`$('.anchor').myReturnStyle()`  and it returns color or an array if there more styles in .anchor

```
$('.anchor').MyReturnStyleValue('color') returns 'green'
```

**BUT**

`$('.anchor').returnStyleValue('border')` returns false as this is not changed by .anchor Class

Comment: There is no easy way of doing what you wish. It would involve parsing the runtime styles. The big question is: why do you need it? It seems fairly useless knowledge to me, maybe there is a better solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: well I'm trying to control jquery by css. without applying 50 classes to an element and using the class values. This may not be valid code, but if it works it would be like jQuery for jQuery. :)

Comment: Example  a $('.aButton').buttonThis()

CSS:
.aButton{
mouseover:'function_doover'; //applies fires function doover
mouseout:'class_classOut'; // adds class classOut
click:'css|opacity:0'; //changes ass
}

The buttonThis would eval the events and apply what the css

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`css(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to achieve this. Please note that:

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported.

Here is an example:

```
<div>
    <a class="anchor">a</a>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
a { background-color: #000; }
.anchor{ color: green; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($($('.anchor').get(0).nodeName).css('background-color'));
});
</script>
```

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fausak/BHRbm/)

Comment: This needs to alert nothing or false. As the .anchor class does not alter the background-color value.

Comment: Are you asking for just the return value of jQuery's `css(..)` method?

Comment: No, let me rephrase. 

Is it possible in javascript or jquery to return the values in an array,object or string of a css class and only that class.